# How to get textfield values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I created a UI by parsing XML (I haven't used a xib file).  That is, I created two text fields and one button. Now I want to get both textfield values when the button is clicked. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your button has this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(getTextValue:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then, make this method (or whatever is in your @selector):

```
-(void)getTextValue:(id)sender {
    NSString *one = yourtextfield.text;
    NSString *two = yourtextfield2.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have created textfield by code and you want to get text of textfield in button action then you can declare textfield in .h file and in your action call

[textfield text];

Answer (score 0):

Use the text property of `UITextField` , like below

```
NSString* myFirstValue = [myFirstTextField.text retain];

NSString* mySecondValue = [mySecondTextField.text retain];
```

after using both value don't forget to release them

```
 [myFirstValue release];
 [mySecondValue release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the text of a **`UITextField`** using

```
NSString *textFieldValue = myTextField.text;
```

or use

```
NSString *textFieldValue = [myTextField text];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare UITextField other wise you cant access the textfields